# Prevent duplicates on insert with billions of rows in SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to determine if there's a practical way to prevent duplicate rows from being inserted into a table using Azure SQL DW when the table already holds billions of rows (say 20 billion).

The root cause of needing this is that the source of the data is a third party that sends over supposedly unique data, but sometimes sends duplicates which have no identifying key. I unfortunately have no idea if we've already received the data they're sending.

What I've tried is to create a table that contains a row hash column (pre-calculated from several other columns) and distribute the data based on that row hash. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [SomeFact]
(
    Row_key BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    EventDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EmailAddress NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    -- other rows
    RowHash BINARY(16) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH(RowHash)
)
```

The insert SQL is approximately:

```
INSERT INTO [SomeFact]
(
    EmailAddress,
    EventDate,
    -- Other rows
    RowHash
)

SELECT
    temp.EmailAddress,
    temp.EventDate,
    -- Other rows
    temp.RowHash
FROM #StagingTable temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [SomeFact] f WHERE f.RowHash = temp.RowHash);
```

Unfortunately, this is just too slow. I added some statistics and even created a secondary index on RowHash and inserts of any real size (10 million rows, for example) won't run successfully without erroring due to transaction sizes. I've also tried batches of 50,000 and those too are simply too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I can think of that wouldn't have the singleton records you have in your query would be to

- Outer join your staging table with the fact table and filter on some NULL values. Assuming You're using Clustered Column Store in your fact table this should be a lot more inexpensive than the above.
- Do a CTAS with a Select Distinct from the existing fact table, and a Select Distinct from the staging table joined together with a UNION.

My gut says the first option will be faster, but you'll probably want to look at the query plan and test both approaches.

Comment: Also worth noting both of these approaches will get slower as the fact table grows. If you have a lot of low cardinality data though the first one should have less of a performance impact as the set grows.

Comment: Can you give a quick example of what the outer join SQL would look like in your suggestion? I'm having a hard time trying to understand your suggestion. I don't have a lot of null values, so I'm confused by the reference. Also, I am using Clustered Column Store indexes for these.

Answer (score 0):

Can you partition the 'main' table by EventDate and, assuming new data has a recent EventDate, CTAS out only the partitions that include the EventDate's of the new data, then 'Merge' the data with CTAS / UNION of the 'old' and 'new' data into a table with the same partition schema (UNION will remove the duplicates) or use the INSERT method you developed against the smaller table, then swap the partition(s) back into the 'main' table.

Note - There is a new option on the partition swap command that allows you to directly 'swap in' a partition in one step:  "WITH (TRUNCATE_TARGET = ON)".

Comment: Unfortunately the new data is not guaranteed to have new event dates. It probably will, but this is not a certainty.

Comment: You can potentially identify which partitions are included then and do some dynamic SQL. Mike's solution is a good one if you can do that. I assumed from your example this was mostly an append only workload that sometimes had duplicates (hence the recommendation I made)

Comment: I understand that the new data will have overlapping event dates with the data currently in the table.  What I was suggesting is select the minimum event date from the new data and CTAS out all of the data from that date forward to a new table.  UNION that with the 'NEW' data to a new table and either use a swap method to put the data back in or delete from the main table from the 'Control' date forward and re-insert the old and new deduped data.

Comment: (continued) If you choose the SWAP method, make sure to pull all of the data for a partition out of the main table before the merge and swap back in.  I.e., let's say the earliest date in the new data is 2/5/2018 and the table is partitioned by Month.  Then you will pull the data from the new table >= '2/1/2018' and UNION it with the new data via CTAS into a partitioned stage table.  Then you will SWAP each partition (FEB and MAR) back into the main table using the option "WITH (TRUNCATE_TARGET = ON)".